# how do you find the vector that minimizes

Tags: numerical-integration, numerical-models

How do you find the vector that minimizes $\|A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}\|_2^2$ ?

Answer (score 0):

$\|A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}\|^2 $

where $\left \| \cdot \right \|$ is the Euclidean norm. In matrix notation the solution, denoted by $\hat{x}$, is given by:

$\hat{x} = (A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}\mathbf{b}$